# How to package multiple python wheels into one wheel on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pip, setuptools, python-wheel

On Windows for Python 2.7- 3.5 is it possible to package multiple python wheels into one wheel?

If not, what are the alternatives using standard library tools?

EDIT

---

I'm planning to use archive to package multiple wheels and extract them after Python installation.

Comment: I am not sure If I understand the goal but check out `buildout`  .. that is what we use for packaging/ deployment http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/

Comment: does buildout support wheels?

Comment: You should be able to write a simple recipe that will execute `pip *.whl`

Comment: We implemented a tool to solve just that. https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/wagon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's rather simple to create a process which does this:

Take Flask, for example:

```
pip wheel flask
```

All your wheels go into the `wheelhouse` dir. Just zip the dir, then, unzip it on the target server and run:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links wheelhouse/ flask
```

We implemented a tool to solve just that though with validation, single file, for both linux and windows and with manylinux1 support.

https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/wagon.